# Content disappeared for authenticated users

Tags: 6, nodes, sessions

Suddenly, I have encountered a weird problem. I see my site flawlessly as admin and unauthenticated users. But all the timestamp-based content (Like blocks-forum thread etc.) disappear when I log in as a (non-admin) user.

I have checked server's time and truncated session table and flushed all cache but the problem persists. Really appreciate your hints.

Comment: Do you check permission of your site?

Comment: Yes. They are untouched since the last time that the site was working fine.

Comment: do you have separate theme for authenticated users?

Comment: The theme is the same for both.

Comment: Try changing the theme and then check the content for authenticated users. Lets see the problem related to theme or something else.

Comment: can you expound upon "timestamp-based" content a bit?  what does that mean? do some node types show up but not others?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin/user/permissions` and then tick the check-box for authenticated users under  **access content** and then click save.

[image]

Comment: It's already ticked. I had not changed the permission settings since the time that site was working ok.